# Close modal dialog when opening link in new browser tab/window

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to close the **modal bootstrap dialog** when the user hits "Open ticket", which in turn opens a new browser window/tab.
Here is my button:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-ticket") + "Open ticket",
      "https://link.to/another/company/url",
      target: '_blank',
      class: 'btn btn-default' 
%>
```

This works fine, but when returning to the calling page, the modal is still open.

I tried to add `data: { dismiss: 'modal' }`, but then the link isn't being opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can suggest you solution,

if you trying like this `data: { dismiss: 'modal' }` you should try like this

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-ticket") + "Open ticket",
      "https://link.to/another/company/url",
      target: '_blank',
      class: 'btn btn-default',
      data-dismiss: 'modal'
%>
```

**Alternate** you can do with jQuery, as you have class selector here `class: 'btn btn-default'` in button to open the link

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-ticket") + "Open ticket",
      "https://link.to/another/company/url",
      target: '_blank',
      class: 'btn btn-default' 
%>
```

Add a customer selector e.g `close-modal`, like `class: 'btn btn-default close-modal'`

and bind the jQuery with selector `close-modal` to close the modal when button clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close-modal').click(function(){
        $('#modalid').modal('hide');  //change #modalid to your bootstrap modal id
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Shehary. The second suggestion perfectly works (after I put the close-modal javascript file into the right directory. First tried in `/app/views/_controller_/`, but better is `/app/assets/javascripts/`.)